# Work-Around needed for Facebook's 'PAGE plugin' error - events, calendar, timeline, etc

Tags: javascript, facebook, error-handling

Facebook's '**PAGE plugin**' https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/page-plugin/
is provided to allow an events/calendar from fb to be displayed in a website.

However, there is a bug - the page/iframe is not displayed if the website visitor is (also) logged into fb.   It works fine is the visitor is NOT a fb user (and is therefore not logged into fb). The bug is already reported to fb  (back in 2021), but they are not responding to peoples' requests. see: https://developers.facebook.com/support/bugs/584988619248795/

The bug produces a console error msg:

> ErrorUtils caught an error: Found null hrp, blocking mods:
> ExceptionDialog; non-blocking mods: ; response error: **1357032**,
> summary: Something went wrong, description: Please try refreshing the
> Page or closing and reopening your browser window.

Is there a javascript way to detect this error, and thus display a suitable msg - rather than the revolving waiting symbols currently displayed.

I found this:
getLoginStatusUrl     here: [Dertermine if user is logged in to Facebook w/o using Facebook api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18682462/dertermine-if-user-is-logged-in-to-facebook-w-o-using-facebook-api)
but don't understand how to use it.

Comment: Using the JS SDK's method to determine the user status probably makes more sense, than doing it the server-side way. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/FB.getLoginStatus/

Comment: @CBroe Is this appropriate? as I don't have an 'app' and the visitor is not logged in to the website, therefor no ID.

Comment: Create an app then, if you want to use this. And the `not_authorized` status would tell you that there is a user logged into Facebook, but not into your app.